# Disable PRINT in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, printing

I have a script with many debug messages, which are printed by `PRINT` function. Is there any way to disable that messages? I have in mind something like `SET NOCOUNT ON`, but for user messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like to set a variable, @Debug tinyint in my scripts/SPs.

Default/set this to 0 to suppress messages, 1 to show messages.

Then instead of using PRINT, use:

```
IF @Debug > 0 RAISERROR( 'Busy doing something...', 0, 1 ) WITH NOWAIT
```

Using WITH NOWAIT forces the message to be displayed immediately and not just when the output buffer is flushed.

As a convention, I use @Debug = 1 for progress messages, @Debug = 2 to include dynmaic SQL, @Debug = 3 to output result sets.

Of course if you have GO batch terminators in your script the variable method won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the simplest solution is the best...
Make all your print statements that deal with debugging as follows:

```
PRINT 'Debug ' + [WhateverStatementsYouDesire]
```

Then you can do a search and replace

```
PRINT 'Debug ' --> --PRINT 'Debug '
```

Do the opposite Find and Replace to turn them back on again...

(I do realize this is not quite what you were asking for but here is what I do for now.
If there is such a switch as you are searching for I would probably change to that method.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to simply comment out all your `PRINT` statements

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, no. There is no #debug  either.

[SSMS tools pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features) has a #debug feature but I've not used it.