# SQL debug print

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, debugging, sqlcmd

If you have 100 occurrences of "PRINT" in your stored procedure, is there a nice way to turn them all on/off when debugging an non-debugging?

I could add a variable `@isdebug = 1`

and later on, do something like
`IF @isdebug = 1 PRINT @yourvar`

and then just set the `@isdebug` to 0 or 1 depending on what you need.
Is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212658/disable-print-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, that is also what I have in procs

```
IF @debug = 1
BEGIN
print 'Something'
--or insert into a log table if you need the rows of a temp table 
--or the results of a calculation
END
```

Answer (score 1):

An expansion of this idea is to setup up a controlling string.  This giving us more options rather than either on or off.

For example:
Stored procedure parameter declaration

```
   (@Debug     varchar(5),  -- use bit wise control for debugging, currently 5 levels.
```

Simple substring to drive a testing/debug block.

```
if substring(@Debug, 1, 1) = '1'
```

For a test run you could enter '10001' for @Debug so that "level" 1 debugs show (ie initialisations) and only "level" 5 debugs show for the sub-section of code you are testing/debugging.

You could expand on this idea by using number values (ie 2-9) too.  But that might be too over the top.