# Prevent print from generating a warning in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**-- EDIT --

I have answered my question but the solution is
more of a work-around. If someone can provide a
real answer I will award the solution to them.

----**

I have searched around for a solution to prevent MS SQL from generating a warning when using print statements in a stored procedure without success.

I am executing this procedure from our ETL application and I need the stored procedure to exit without errors or warnings.

FYI - The print statements are not needed when the stored procedure is executed by the ETL process.  Those are there for when it is executed manually.

I have tried SET ANSI WARNINGS OFF and Try/Catch but I am still getting warnings on the output.

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spBackupSomeTables]
AS
BEGIN TRY
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
    PRINT 'Copying SomeTable1 to Z_Backup_SomeTable1' +  CHAR(10)
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
    TRUNCATE TABLE  Z_Backup_SomeTable1
    INSERT INTO   Z_Backup_SomeTable1
    SELECT *
    FROM   SomeTable1

    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
    PRINT 'Copying SomeTable2 to Z_Backup_SomeTable2' +  CHAR(10)
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
    TRUNCATE TABLE  Z_Backup_SomeTable2
    INSERT INTO   Z_Backup_SomeTable2
    SELECT *
    FROM   SomeTable2

    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
    PRINT 'All Done' +  CHAR(10)
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    DECLARE     
        @ErrorNumber   VARCHAR(1000),
        @ErrorSeverity   VARCHAR(1000),
        @ErrorState   VARCHAR(1000),
        @ErrorProcedure   VARCHAR(1000),
        @ErrorLine   VARCHAR(1000),
        @ErrorMessage   VARCHAR(1000)


    SET @ErrorNumber = (SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber)
    SET @ErrorSeverity = (SELECT ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity)
    SET @ErrorState = (SELECT ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState)
    SET @ErrorProcedure = (SELECT ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure)
    SET @ErrorLine = (SELECT ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine)
    SET @ErrorMessage = (SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage)


    PRINT 'ErrorNumber: ' + @ErrorNumber + CHAR(10)
    PRINT 'ErrorSeverity: ' + @ErrorSeverity + CHAR(10)
    PRINT 'ErrorState: ' + @ErrorState + CHAR(10)
    PRINT 'ErrorProcedure: ' + @ErrorProcedure + CHAR(10)
    PRINT 'ErrorLine: ' + @ErrorLine + CHAR(10)
    PRINT 'ErrorMessage: ' + @ErrorMessage + CHAR(10)

END CATCH
GO
```

This is the execution result:

```
 Warnings: ---> 
   W (1): Copying SomeTable1 to Z_Backup_SomeTable1
   W (2): Copying SomeTable2 to Z_Backup_SomeTable2
   W (3): All Done
```

Comment: you could add some parameter to differentiate when you run it manually or through an ETL, and use the `print` accordingly

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212658/disable-print-in-sql-server

Comment: Regarding "prevent MS SQL from generating a warning when using print statements in a stored procedure": can you please be more specific. What warnings, exactly, are you seeing? Using `PRINT` in a Stored Procedure does not generate any warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Using suggestions/links in the comments, this is the solution I came up with..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spBackupSomeTables] @Debug tinyint =1
AS
BEGIN

     IF @Debug IS NULL
        SET @Debug = 1;    

     IF @Debug > 0 
        RAISERROR( 'Copying SomeTable1 to Z_Backup_SomeTable1', 0, 1 ) WITH NOWAIT
    TRUNCATE TABLE  Z_Backup_SomeTable1
    INSERT INTO   Z_Backup_SomeTable1
    SELECT *
    FROM   SomeTable1

    IF @Debug > 0 
        RAISERROR( 'Copying SomeTable2 to Z_Backup_SomeTable2', 0, 1 ) WITH NOWAIT
    TRUNCATE TABLE  Z_Backup_SomeTable2
    INSERT INTO   Z_Backup_SomeTable2
    SELECT *
    FROM   SomeTable2

    IF @Debug > 0 
        RAISERROR( 'All Done', 0, 1 ) WITH NOWAIT
END
GO
```

The @Debug paramter is defaulted to a value of 1 so that humans don't have to worry about passing any parameters in order to view the printed status messages.  The ETL job will simply pass a value of 0 for that parameter to suppress the print statements allowing the job to complete without any (false) warnings.